# Spring can't unmarshall bean when using Spring security

Tags: spring, jaxb, spring-security

I have a bean which extends from org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User and using this bean with openID. The bean looks like:

```
package com.employee;

import java.util.Collection;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;

@XmlRootElement(name="Employee")
public class Employee extends User{

    private int empId;
    private String deptName;

    public Employee() {
        super("", "unused", null);
    }
     public Employee(String username, Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
           super(username, "unused", authorities);
       }

    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }
    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }
    public String getDeptName() {
        return deptName;
    }
    public void setDeptName(String deptName) {
        this.deptName = deptName;
    }
}
```

The controller accepts an instance of Employee as:

@RequestMapping(value = "/addEmp.do", 
            method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee emp) {...}

I have sent a POST request with following body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Employee>
    <empId>10</empId>
    <deptName>abc</deptName>
</Employee>
```

But getting the following JAXB exception on invoking the addEmp operation:

```
2012-12-16 15:25:55,364{HH:mm:ss} DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:132) -
Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.main.EmpController.addEmployee(com .employee.Employee)]: 
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not unmarshal to 
[class com.employee.Employee]: Unable to create an instance of com.employee.Employee; nested exception is 
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Unable to create an instance of com.employee.Employee
```

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing more in the logs from JAXB? Have you tried invoking JAXB manually with this input (in some playground project)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message:

> Unable to create an instance of com.employee

may imply that the input does not provide valid employee properties. In the constructor

```
public Employee() {
    super("", "unused", null);
}
```

the default username is set to '', but spring security does not accept blank username.

Comment: That looks like the probable cause of this problem because it was working until I introduced userdetails stuff. Will try passing some dummy value for username and see if it fixes. I am not using username so I left it as blank. Probably would also need to generate unique username for each user.

Comment: You may use empId.toString() as username if it is unique and not nullable. Also you may need to provide some other properties like password, enabled(T/F), passwordExpired, accountExpired, accountLocked, etc., if they are not set to be nullable.

Comment: empId.toString() doesn't work in constructor because empId is a member variable. Could you please let me know how can set the fields like password, enabled etc. as nullable? I even tried "super(String.valueOf((new Random()).nextInt()), "unused", null);" but it didn't work.

Comment: About the properties like password, refer to the API doc: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html, the constructor is like:  User(String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities). Your super() method may misses some properties. Random() is fine for small number of data, but for larger amounts, UUID or ObjectId works better.